# How to stream file in WCF using NetTcpBinding? (got exception)

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have the following code:

**Client side:**

```
public bool Connect(string IPAdress, string Port, string UniqueName)
{
        try
        {
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://"+IPAdress+":"+Port+"/"+UniqueName));

            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
            m_Factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IServerService>(this, binding, address);

            m_Service = m_Factory.CreateChannel();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error
            return false;
        }
}
```

**Server side**

```
 public void Start(string Port, string UniqueName) {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://127.0.0.1:" + Port + "/" + UniqueName);
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.None;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
        binding.TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Streamed;
        try
        {
            m_ServiceHost = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(this, baseAddress);

            m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServerService), binding, baseAddress);
            m_ServiceHost.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I tried creating the binding as buffered but when I tried to send a FileStream the server side got the instance empty, as I read that I need to use streamed transfare mode.

I get the follwing exception in the client side in the line

```
m_Service = m_Factory.CreateChannel();
```

> *Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'NetTcpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.*

Comment: in your client code, you are creating a duplex channel. What does your interface look like? Is your service setup to do duplex calling/callbacks?  If not, change to use a standard ChannelFactory.

Comment: I have duplex calling and callback in my interfaces.